# Is it possible to change the task creation options of an async method?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have an async method that I want to give the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` flag. This is easy with a non-async method invoked by a wrapping `Task`:

```
void Foo() { Thread.Sleep(5000); }
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Foo, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
Console.WriteLine(task.CreationOptions);
// LongRunning
```

Or any of a number of variants (Task.Run, new Task, etc.). However, there doesn't seem to be a way for methods defined as async and return a `Task`:

```
async Task FooAsync() { await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0)); }
Task fooTask = FooAsync();
Console.WriteLine(FooTask.CreationOptions);
// None
```

Trying to wrap it in a long running tasks is a null starter as well:

```
async Task FooAsync() { await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0)); }
Task<Task> wrapTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(FooAsync, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
Console.WriteLine(wrapTask.CreationOptions);
// LongRunning
Console.WriteLine(wrapTask.Unwrap().CreationOptions);
// None
```

In that case, `wrapTask` is indeed `LongRunning`, but it returns almost immediately (soon after `FooAsync` calls `await Task.Delay(...)`) so setting that flag is actually probably undesirable. The thing I want to await, ultimately, is `wrapTask.Unwrap()`.

In my testing I have found that, in fact, the code in `FooAsync` executes in a threadpool thread after returning from an `await`. It is, per normal, invoked on the calling thread but it does not attempt to resume execution on the calling thread afterwards.

I would expect this might be controllable via method attributes, but there are none that I can find that would help here. Is it possible to change the creation options that the compiler generates for an async method? Does it even make sense to try?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Your question doesn't really make any sense, because an `async` method isn't a thread. It doesn't start a thread, it doesn't represent a thread, it is not in any useful way related to a thread.

An `async` method is asynchronous only to the extent that it awaits *other* asynchronous operations. That's all. Only in the case where those operations are started as actual threads (e.g. `Task.Run()`) would there even *be* a thread to describe as long-running, and in that case you have access to the options you want, when you call `Task.Run()`.

If your `async` method itself is in fact long-running, then why make the method `async` in the first place? You could just hold the thread with a synchronous wait on other asynchronous operations. IMHO it's not ideal, but you've already accepted that you're going to hold on to the thread for an extended period of time, so why not even longer?

Alternatively, maybe you just mean that the awaits could take a long time. In that case, it wouldn't even be correct to use the option `LongRunning`, because that is telling the scheduler that your operation is going to hold a thread for an extended period of time. Your complaint seems to be that *"the code…executes in a threadpool thread after returning from an `await`"*. But your code wasn't actually holding a thread while awaiting, so it wasn't really long-running.

If you have elements of your method that *do* actually run for extended periods of time before yielding the thread via `await` and you don't want to block the current thread for other awaits in the method, then it seems to me you should refactoring those *parts* of the `async` method which are long-running into their own method, which you can execute via `Task.Run()`. Then your `async` method can await those without blocking the current thread, *and* you can indicate to the thread scheduler that those specific portions of the operation *are* long-running (i.e. by passing the option to `Task.Run()`).

Comment: +1 for the phrase "your code wasn't actually holding a thread while awaiting, so it wasn't really long-running" - really sums up the whole thing